# Jquery remove class hidden onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have following HTML Structure:

```
<div class="form-step2 hidden"></div>
<div class="form-step2 hidden"></div>
<div class="form-step2 hidden"></div>
<div class="form-step2 hidden"></div>
<button type="button" id="addblock" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">+</button>
```

If i click on the button i want to remove one hidden and than the next hidden.
My JS:

```
$( "#addblock" ).click(function() {
$( ".form-step2" ).next(".form-step2").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

But this removes all hidden

Answer (score 3):

Remove the hidden class from the first `form-step2` element with class `hidden`

```js
$("#addblock").click(function() {
  $(".form-step2.hidden:first").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-step2 hidden">1</div>
<div class="form-step2 hidden">2</div>
<div class="form-step2 hidden">3</div>
<div class="form-step2 hidden">4</div>
<button type="button" id="addblock" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">+</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$("#addblock").click(function() {
  $('.hidden:first').removeClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-step2 hidden">A</div>
<div class="form-step2 hidden">B</div>
<div class="form-step2 hidden">C</div>
<div class="form-step2 hidden">D</div>
<button type="button" id="addblock" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$( "#addblock" ).click(function() {
    var $step = $( ".form-step2" ).not('.hidden');
    if($step.length<1)
    {
       $( ".form-step2:first" ).removeClass("hidden");
     }
     else
    {
      $step.next(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

u can try this:

http://codepen.io/pallavi1811/pen/KpBjNL

```
$( "#addblock" ).click(function() {
  $( ".form-step2" ).siblings(".form-step2").eq(1).removeClass("hidden");
});
```